# Html and Css: Image Menu Linking

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a menu bar which uses image buttons.On my menu bar, I can see my images on it but I can not click them. I used text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; in my css file to hide links text. My link text became hidden but links became inactive. Moreover i tried text-indent:-9999px; but result was same. I could not find the problem maybe my html or css structure is wrong. Could you pls check it ?

I updated html and css file on jsfiddle

```
 <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/kt2hL/8/"> jsfiddle</a>
```

Comment: How do we access the local images . btw here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt2hL/) edit this and update your question

Comment: Quick thought, don't you need to apply the indent to the contents of the anchor element rather than to the element itself?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
nav ul li a{display: block}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Working

```
nav ul li a
{ 
    display: block
}
```